# Select2 não abre quando tela é menor

Tags: jquery, formulário, bootstrap-3, jquery-select2

Estou com problema quando o select2 está em um formulário e perto do fim da tela, dessa forma ele não abre porque entende que não há espaço suficiente, gostaria de saber como fazer nesse caso.

Os campos que estão mais acima funcionam mas quando chega mais próximo do fim da página esses campos não abrem por causa do tamanho da tela, se fosse um select normal ele abriria as opções acima mas como é select2 não abre.

[image: Cliquei no select2 mas ele não abre]

Comment: Bem vindo ao StackOverflow em Português! Por favor explique melhor o problema, e se possível inclua um [exemplo de código que reproduza o que está acontecendo](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), pois está ampla demais a sua pergunta. Veja na central de ajuda [como Perguntar](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: O select2 abre para cima automáticamente se não tiver espaço. Não está a acontecer isso? podes fazer um jsFiddle a demonstrar o problema?

Comment: Resolvi o problema, no css do Body da página estava com "position:relative", desativei esta propriedade e voltou a funcionar o select2, obrigado!!